# How can I put data from my datagridview to textboxes?

Tags: c#, sql-server

What I want to do is when I select the row of the data in my database, it will go to textbox. For example the data in column "Title" will go to textbox1 and the data in column "ISBN" will go to textbox2.  I haven't edit any properties in Properties window of datagridview. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your query and if you can post some of your code .

Comment: Post your gridview and code containing textboxes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
yourTextBox.Text = yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Title"].Value.ToString();
yourTextBox2.Text = yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["ISBN"].Value.ToString();
```

EDIT: I assume that you have selected the row on your datagrid. I´m sorry for the mistake, it was Cells property instead of Columns

Hope that helps.

Comment: It has an red underline in the word Columns. It says that "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridviewRow' does not contain a definition for 'Columns'.

Comment: @NicoRiff I am sorry but can you check your code in real ? For me it wasn't working , by the way still trying to figure what `ana` wants .

Comment: @AnaalexisCenteno I just want you to elaborate your question a bit , See you want to edit your gridview row in different page ?? i mean you want those column values in textboxes ??

Comment: @surajsingh In my project I want two columns only. The Title Column and ISBN column. I want to transfer or put that in the textboxes which is textbox1 and textbox2.

Comment: @AnaalexisCenteno **How** you want to pass i mean is there is any event or what if not why don't bind it by your **datsource** directly ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **CellClick** event of the DataGridView tool.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  textbox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Title"].Value.ToString();
  textbox2.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ISBN"].Value.ToString();
}
```